# Route issue in Laravel with several controllers and different route with same name

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have added below routes in web.php but it's not working.

```
Route::post('show', [
'as' => 'usersinformation.show',
'uses' => 'usersinformationController@show'


 ]);



 Route::post('store', [
    'as' => 'usersinformation.store',
    'uses' => 'usersinformationController@store'
  ]);



 Route::get('store',[usersController::class, 'store'])->name('usersinformation.store');
    Route::post('/store', 'usersController@store');
    Route::post('store',[usersController::class, 'store'])->name('users.store');
    Route::get('/index', 'usersController@index');
```

my controller is as below and I am using Ajax to send data but the error I receive is Method not allowed exception.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $fname = $request -> fname;
    $lname = $request -> lname;
    $pnumber = $request -> pnumber; 

    
}
```

Ajax Code ----------------

```
data = {
    _token: $('input#usersinformation-token').val(),
    'fname': $('input#first_name').val(), 
    'lname': $('input#last_name').val(),
    'pnumber': $('input#phonenumber').val()

};
$.post(url, data, function(data, status){
    alert('working' + data + "    " + status );
    $('div#load-content').html(data);
} );
```

Comment: you are sending the post request to what URL?

Comment: you have define post with store multiple time  try this `Route::post('/store',[usersController::class, 'store'])->name('store');`  and comment out rest

Comment: url for ajax post request is :   http://127.0.0.1:8000/usersinformation/store   and the route that has been mentioned is : {{route('usersinformation.store')}}

Comment: @syedjawwadalam the route that you've mentioned doesn't work. it seems that this is not the controller that I am sending request to.

Comment: @syedjawwadalam I have added the proper answer for this and you can use it if anytime you face route issues in Laravel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by very much adding namespaces to my route contents like below:

```
route::post('usersinformation/store', 'usersinformationController@store');
route::post('usresinformation/destroy', 'usersinformationController@destroy');
```

you can easily manage your routes by adding routes like above that I have added and will never face issues for the routes.